# stop user feedback to copy command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy

I use the following batch command to copy a file

```
@COPY /Y app_offline_template.htm app_offline.htm
```

However it always gives feedback in the batch file to the user eg. 1 file copied etc.

Is there a switch to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@COPY /Y app_offline_template.htm app_offline.htm > NUL
```